# React hooks where should i execute function? Parent or child?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a react native app using react hooks. Should I execute function in each functional component or execute it the screen component and pass the data back to the component but this doesn't sound right to the idea of react hooks. 
For example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and render this component in the screen component? or 
Which one is the best practice of doing react hooks.

**Update**

What I am trying to say is Should I execute function in the parent or child. In my work, my parent component hold many functions and code and I realise that my child didn't have much code.
 For example, fetching the data from api and do the `count` function. Should I do all the code in parent? or pass the api data to child to do the `count`? 
That's what I am questioning about.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand your question. Could you expand a little bit more, please?

Comment: It's totally unclear what do you want to achieve, please provide more details.

Comment: You lift state, this will help you understand https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for not making it clear enough .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on which `Components` owns the state. In the above code,

`Screen` --> Parent component

`Example` -> Child component

In this case, it makes sense for `count` should be local to the `child` and `parent` should need not have any knowledge about count. If you move this to the `parent`, then the `parent` component will be rendered unnecessarily ( not really a concern as React is really fast, but this can be a problem if your app starts growing ).

If count is needed in the `parent` component, to compute something, then it makes sense to move `count` computation to the `parent` and then pass that as props to the `child`. It all depends on the behavior.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering my question if we lift up the state why do we need to create child component? so we don't need to pass the data around.